# django cache_page how to set version

Tags: python, django, decorator

I can set version by `cache.set`:

```py
cache.set(key, value, timeout=60, version=1)
```

but how to set by cache_page decorator?

like:

```py
@cache_page(60, version=1)
def view(request):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an entry to the CACHES (you would have to add the dictionary) dictionary in your settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    },
    'my_cache': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'VERSION': 1 # Or of your preference
    }
}
```

Now in your decorator you would specify:

```
@cache_page(60, cache="my_cache")
def view(request):
```

Answer (score 0):

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) mentions that the cache decorator can only take a single argument and 2 optional none of which are for versioning, im afraid you will have to use the cache functions for versioning or attempt to add your own functionality to the decorators.

edit:
the only way to set version is with

```
incr_version('my_key')
```

and

```
decr_version('my_key')
```